# Complex Integral which is not a line integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying make sense of the following function: $$f(z):= \int_{|w|<1}\frac{dw}{z-w}.$$ In particular, I am trying to show that $f$ is holomorphic in the annulus $1<|z|<\infty$.

My question is: How do we make sense of the function $f(z)?$ What I mean is that since it is not a line integral I am quite confused.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: As written the integral doesn't make sense as $dw$ is a line element. Area elements in complex analysis are either of the form $$\operatorname{Re}\{dw\}\wedge \operatorname{Im}\{dw\}$$ or $$\frac{dw\wedge d\bar{w}}{2i}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|z| >1$, the integrand $\frac1{z-w}$ is holomorphic on the disk $|w| < 1$. Applying the Cauchy's theorem, we have that the integral equals 0.

As for your question, you should calculate the integral by the defintion.

For instance, assume $|z| < 1$, denote $C_r = \{w \big| |w-z| < r\}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \int_{|w| < 1} \frac{dw}{z - w} \\
&= \int_{C_r} \frac{dw}{z - w} \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d(z + re^{i\theta})}{z - (z+re^{i\theta})} \\
&=-2\pi i
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Unless stated otherwise, I think your interpretation of the problem is more correct than OP's and the integral in question *is* a line integral, with the notation meaning, choose any circle $|w|<1$